# render partial view dynamic without return to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-web-api2

i have **div**(**ContentPartial**) that i use it to load with partial view .

note that this partial view not constant ,it is name dynamically from database , some times it is students some times it is employees and so on ,......

i am using **MVC in front end** and **web API in back end** , i don't like to return mvc controller to view partial view , i need to view partial view with j query like html render

this is my div

```
<div class="ContentPartial hidden">                            
</div>
```

and this is my ajax request to load partial view from mvc controller

```
  $.ajax({
            URL: "/" + controllerName + "/" + ActionName + "",                
            data: JSON.parse(requestData),

            success: function (data) {  
                    $('.ContentPartial').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('.ContentPartial').html(data);

                  }
        })
```

and this is my contoller that return partial view

```
 public ActionResult ActionName()
    {          
        return PartialView("ActionName");
    }
```

i want something like that

```
$('.ContentPartial').renderpartial('dynamic view name')
```

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC is a server-side framework, and jquery is a client side library. you can't render a view without doing a request.

But you could do a controller that renders a view with the name as a parameter

```
public RendererController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Render(string viewName)
    {
        return PartialView(viewName);
    }
}
```

and clientside:

```
function renderPartial($container, viewName) {
    $.ajax({
        URL: "/Renderer/Render?viewName=" + viewName,                
            success: function (data) {  
                $container.html(data);
                $container.show();
            }
    });
}

renderPartial($('.ContentPartial'), 'dynamic view name');
```

Note that your views needs to be in the shared folders for the controller to find them without the full path.